# JavaFX Embedded MediaPlayer reverses blue and red color for MP4 videos

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi, gluon

I'm using Gluon (embedded) SDK on Raspberry Pi (Rasbian) and the JavaFX MediaPlayer class to plays MP4 videos and it appears to reverse the blue and red colors.  Simply using the media player that comes with Rasbian works fine.

Comment: Could you provide some more details? Raspberry Pi version, OS, JavaFX SDK version etc.

Comment: Raspberry Pi 3+
OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
jdk1.8.0_201
Glouan: JavaFX armv6hf SDK 11.0.2